# guidelines for writing fast CSS

Tags: css

If I Google for CSS optimisation, the results are generally about some kind of compression tools. Forgetting transmisison/parsing speed for now, I am wondering what guidelines there are for writing rules which are fast to *apply* to a document.

Basic example:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="x">...</div>
    <div class="y">...</div>
</div>
<div class="b">
    <div class="x">...</div>
    <div class="y">...</div>
</div>
```

versus

```
<div class="a x">...</div>
<div class="a y">...</div>
<div class="b x">...</div>
<div class="b y">...</div>
```

The CSS for these would require different selectors:

```
.b .x {...}
```

versus

```
.b.x {...}
```

In terms of performance, is there any reason to favour the former or the latter? Sure, **it will depend on the selector engine**, but perhaps the CSS rules lend themselves to a natural implementation algorithm that all engines will have.

Do we know how to estimate the cost of different selectors which are equivalent, given a document?

Are there guidelines for this somewhere?

Are they browser-specific or universal?

Comment: Isn't it pointless to adjust CSS thinking rendering engine would render it faster? What is true is that - smaller CSS = faster download = less bandwith = faster rendering. I doubt that having a space between dots yields any performance penalties, and if it does they are probably so infinitely small that they don't need to be accounted for. CSS is made for styling, please don't start the trend of typing CSS in such a way that makes it "faster to render" :)

Comment: The whitespace is syntax, it **completely** changes the meaning of the selection operation. It will use a different algorithm and yield different results in general. The question is: in the case that the two methods give the same results, which is faster. *It's not about saving a byte!*

Comment: I'll just say this: you can't *rely* on implementation details. Also, since you said it **completely** changes the meaning of the selection operation, **performance is out of the question, period.**

Comment: Also, if you have to change your markup to cater to CSS rendering performance, that's one more level of doing it wrong.

Comment: Sometimes performance is a feature. I'm not saying we should write code for the machine's benefit all the time, but sometimes you have to.

Comment: While interesting, this is a bit broad for Stack Overflow. Questions like this typically just attract a lot of, well ... _not so great_ answers a long with a steady stream of chatty comments.

Answer (score 0):

If i saw your example i personal prefer second one because it reduce my HTML markup but there is not much effect in CSS. If the mark up is less it's take less time to write the code & also less time to load the page.